# Add UIView to UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiview

I have a ViewController, on it i have a UIView space:

Here it is:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *iboContentView;
```

So, i have created a *.XIB file called ExternalDisplayViewController.xib
And the created ExternalDisplayViewController.h and ExternalDisplayTableViewController.m

The in ExternalDisplayViewController.xib to my UIView i added class ExternalDisplayTableViewController ( to tie up classes to UI ).

And on my ViewController i want to place my Custom control ( that is ExternalDisplayTableViewController ) into its place - iboContentView.

In my code i do this:

```
-(void)showViewController
{
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.iboContentView.frame.size.width, self.iboContentView.frame.size.height);
    ExternalDisplayViewController *view = [[ExternalDisplayViewController alloc]initWithFrame:frame];
    view.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    view.contentMode=UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    [self.iboContentView addSubview: view];    
}
```

**But it doesn't show up. What am i doing wrong?**

Here how my Custom control looks like:

[image]

ExternalDisplayViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ExternalDisplayViewController : UIView

@end
```

Comment: Please note variable names (Such as `View` in this case) should start with lower case, so `View` should be `view`. And this looks like you are trying to add a viewController to a view not a view to a view. Try `[self.iboContentView addSubview:View.view];`

Comment: No, i 100% know that my UIView is not a UIViewController. Because i created an empty xib and placed UIView there and tied it to UIView classes

Comment: The code posted would not compile.  If it's running, please copy the real code.

Comment: So this confuses me then if `view` isn't a viewController why are you allocating `ExternalDisplayTableViewController` which clearly says it is a viewController? If `ExternalDisplayTableViewController` is not a viewController then you shouldn't be calling it a viewController. What does the interface look like for `ExternalDisplayTableViewController`? @danh this whole question seems a bit Cheesy (Haha see what I did there)

Comment: See the added attachment

Comment: That tells us nothing. I want to see what's in your `ExternalDisplayTableViewController.h` file.

Comment: added code of ExternalDisplayViewController.h

Comment: I have pasted all the codes, so what do you think about it? Except that i called the controls not correctly =)

Comment: So, your `ExternalDisplayViewController` is actually a view and not a view controller at all!

Comment: `ExternalDisplayViewController` needs renaming to just `ExternalDisplayView` There is a huge difference between `View` and `ViewController` and as it has it will create a lot of confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UIView *view = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ExternalDisplayTableViewController" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
[iboContentView addSubview:view]
```

Comment: feel free to mark it as the answer if it solved your problem :)

Comment: Sorry, but this loads a xib, but my code files don't get triggered

Comment: this adds your xib view to your view controller's main view. if there's something else you need it to do that it's not doing, that would seem to be a different problem